# Kohana 3.2 External Validation

Tags: php, kohana

I'm not sure how to get external error messages to show.

Field

```
<?php echo Form::input('membername', $username, array('id' => 'username')); ?><?php echo Arr::get($errors, 'membername');?>
```

Controller

```
try 
{       
    $extra_rules = Validation::factory($this->request->post())
        ->rule('membername', 'not_empty');

    $username->update($extra_rules);
}
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $ex) 
{
    $errors = $ex->errors('models/user');
}
```

/models/user/_external.php

```
return array(
    'membername' => array(
        'not_empty' => 'You must provide a member name.',
    ),
);
```

When the field is empty no error messages appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Kohana can't find the correct message, and therefore shows nothing.

If `membername` is a member of your model `user`, the error message should be defined in `/models/user.php` instead of `/models/user/_external.php`.

---

Edit:
If `membername` is not a member of the model, the error should be available via : `<?php echo Arr::path($errors, '_external.membername'); ?>`

Comment: It's not a member. I've been researching and it seems that if the field name is not a column name I should do external validation, such as if it was password_confirm. I'm not sure why it's not finding the message.

Comment: The documentation indicates to use `<?php echo Arr::path($errors, '_external.password_confirm'); ?>`, I don't know if it's related to the fact that it's not a member, of if the field name is `_external[password_confirm]`. What's the output of `var_dump($errors)` ?